# IIS 7.5 Configuration - Integrated security

Tags: asp.net, iis-7.5

Please let me know how to set integrated security = true in IIS 7.5 . Thanks

Comment: Please provide more details. in which context you need this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Select your web site in **IIS Manager**.
2. Double-click the **Authentication** icon under the **IIS** header.
3. Right-click on **Windows Authentication** and select **Enable**.

Comment: sorry, my mistake, i could not see the authentication configuration since it wasnt installed. I installed and followed the answer above.